# Definite integrals that are hard using the FTC but doable from first principles

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, soft-question, examples-counterexamples

When I was introduced to integration, I was briefly exposed to the definition of a Riemann sum, and as an illustration we worked out a couple of definite integrals directly from this definition:
$$
\int\limits_a^b f\left(x\right)\,dx = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} f\left(x_k\right) \Delta x, \qquad \Delta x = \frac{b-a}{n}, \qquad x_k = a + k\Delta x
$$
These turned out to be fairly tedious, and I was quickly shown that the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (FTC) provides a much more convenient way of doing things.

I am wondering if there are any examples of definite integrals that are hard to evaluate using the FTC because the antiderivative of $f(x)$ is hard to find, yet are amenable to being worked out directly from the definition.

Answer (score 3):

Let $C$ be the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set).
Define 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1 & x\not \in C\\
0&x \in C\\
\end{cases}$$

Then $\int_0^1 f(x)dx =1$.

(And is well defined as a Riemann integral.)